# Porcentaje superior por semana, mes, año, etc. ¿Qué significa?

Tags: soporte, reputación

Recientemente he estado revisando mi perfil de Stack Overflow en español y en relación a la reputación he visto algunas anotaciones que han ido cambiando: el viernes de la pasada semana me ponía una anotación con "3% superior esta semana" y que ahora ha sido reemplazada por "5% superior este mes".

¿Alguien me puede decir qué significan esos porcentajes y qué implican exactamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si pulsas sobre el mensaje, te lleva a [esta sección](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/637/month/es-stackoverflow/2019-02-01/115451#115451) donde muestra un ranking de usuarios en función de la reputación obtenida durante el periodo de tiempo seleccionado. En este caso, durante un mes.

Lo que significa es:

Si a todos los usuarios que han ganado reputación este mes los metes en 100 grupos, entonces tú estarías en el 5nto grupo de gente con mayor reputación conseguida.

Por lo que los datos son puramente estadísticas para que te ubiques en el global de usuarios y puedas ver cómo lo estás haciendo en comparación con el resto.

No tiene ninguna implicación dentro de la comunidad y no hay ninguna medalla asociada a estas clasificaciones.

---

Supongo que te cambió de *semana* a *mes* porque durante la semana fuiste top, pero pasado ese periodo tenías un puesto muy bajo en el ranking semanal y por eso muestra ahora el mensual, donde tienes el puesto #26.

En mi caso, me figura un porcentaje del general (*"of all time"*)  ya que no he tenido grandes obtenciones de reputación ni durante el año, ni semestre ni mes ni semana en comparación con otros usuarios :)